# Django computed column with lookup from same table and if class

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to programming. I am trying to create a project management site. I created a model as follows:

```
class Boqmodel(models.Model):
        code = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
        building = models.ForeignKey(building, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
        level = models.ForeignKey(level, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
        activity = models.ForeignKey(activity, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
        subactivity = models.ForeignKey(sub_activity, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
        duration = models.IntegerField()
        linkactivity = models.IntegerFeild(null=True) #contains code (same as code field) which this specific code is linked to
        linktype = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)# only two choices start or finish
        linkduration = models.IntegerField(null=True)
        plannedstart = models.DateField()
        plannedfinish = models.DateField()
```

The problem is I need my planned start as a computed column. The planned column should be as follows:

- if linkactivity is null, then it should take a default value 01-01-2019
- if else then it should look the linkactivity in code field and then

  - if linktype is start, then it should specify the start date of code activity +duration
  - or if linktype is finish plannedfinish + duration

Example

First entry:

```
code=1
building=A-1
Level=L-1
Activity=Activity-1
Subactivity-Subactivity-1
duration=2
linkactivity=null
linktype=null
linkduration=null
planned start=01-01-2019(as linkactivity=null)
plannedfinish=03-01-2019(planned start+duration)
```

Second entry:

```
code=2
building=A-1
Level=L-1
Activity=Activity-2
Subactivity-Subactivity-2
duration=3
linkactivity=1
linktype=start
linkduration=1
planned start=02-01-2019(as linkactivity=1,it searches code1 ,as linktype=start,it searches startdate of code 1 it is 01-01-2019 ; finally 01-01-2019+link duration(1)=02-01-2019)
plannedfinish=05-01-2019(planned start+duration)
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `Model.objects.create()` method, the django ORM implicitly calls the `Model.save()` method inside your model. Since, you are inheriting `BoqModel` from `models.Model` and there is no explicit `BoqModel.save()` method in your `BoqModel`, `Model.objects.create()` method calls the `save()` method from the parent class. Inside `Model.save()` method you can customize your model save behavior. In order to achieve your intended action, override the `save()` method as follows -

```
class Boqmodel(models.Model):
    code = models.IntegerField()
    building = models.ForeignKey(building, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    level = models.ForeignKey(level, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(activity, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    subactivity = models.ForeignKey(sub_activity, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    linkactivity = models.IntegerFeild(null=True) #contains code (same as code field) which this specific code is linked to
    linktype = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)# only two choices start or finish
    linkduration = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    plannedstart = models.DateField()
    plannedfinish = models.DateField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.linkactivity is None:
            self.plannedstart = datetime.date(year=2019, month=1, day=1)
        else:
            boq = BoqModel.objects.get(code=self.linkactivity)

            if self.linktype is not None:
                if self.linktype == "start":
                    self.plannedstart = boq.plannedstart + datetime.timedelta(days=self.linkduration)
                elif self.linktype == "finish":
                    self.plannedstart = boq.plannedfinish + datetime.timdelta(days=self.linkduration)
                else:
                    self.plannedstart = datetime.date(year=2019, month=1, day=1)
            else:
                self.plannedstart = datetime.date(year=2019, month=1, day=1)
        self.plannedfinish = self.plannedstart + datetime.tiemdelta(days=self.linkduration)

        super(BoqModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The above is not optimized. But you get the general idea of how to do it. Also learn more about overriding predefined model methdos [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods).